# Get the content of json file on page load

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am using ajax, php and json to store click counts in json file...Let's say the file is this:

> count.json

```
{"countbtn1":28,"countbtn2":25,"countbtn3":39}
```

> downloadsCount.php

```
<?php
    $buttonName=$_POST["buttonName"];
    $file = "count.json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
    echo $json['count'.$buttonName] ; 
?>
```

> downloads.php

```
<?php
    $buttonName=$_POST["buttonName"];
    $file = "downloads.json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
    $json['count'.$buttonName] = $json['count'.$buttonName] + 1;
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json));
    echo 'success';
?>
```

> And I need to place each btn value inside these on page load:

```
<div class='smallbtn1'>0</div>
<div class='smallbtn2'>0</div>
<div class='smallbtn3'>0</div>
```

> Counting and updating the json file with this:

```
$('.download').click(function() { 
    //get name of button
    var name= $(this).prop('name');
    $.ajax({
        url: "downloads.php",
        data:{buttonName:name},
        method: "POST",
        success: function(response) {
            if (response = 'success') { 
                //get count download
                $.ajax({
                    url: "downloadsCount.php",
                    data:{buttonName:name},
                    method: "POST",
                    success: function(response){
                            $('.small'+name).html(response);                            
                        }                   
                });     
            }
        }
    });
    return true;
  });
```

> ..and I tried updating the count on page load with this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "downloadsCount.php", 
    data:{buttonName:name}, 
    method: "POST", 
    success: function(response){ 
        $('.small'+name).html(response); } 
    }); 

 });
```

...but it doesn't update the values on load, just after the first click.

**PS:** The whole thing IS wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){..});`

Comment: If you console.log(response), what does it give you? BTW see @TiiJ7 's comment

Comment: `if (response = 'success')` typo (needs to be `==`)

Comment: @YankiTwizzy it says : Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: @TiiJ7 That is not the problem...I updated the script and it's not that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing the code on your server, I'd say the issue is how you are calling the AJAX. You are doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ 
    url: "downloadsCount.php", 
    data:{buttonName:name}, 
    method: "POST", 
    success: function(response){ 
        $('.small'+name).html(response); } 
    }); 
});
```

But you don't have defined what `name` is (it is defined on the click event, but not when the page is loaded for the first time). You should do something like this:

```
$(".download").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "downloadsCount.php", 
        data:{buttonName:name }, 
        method: "POST", 
        success: function(response){ 
            $('.small'+name).html(response); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

So the AJAX is called for each one of the buttons, and you use the attribute `name` by doing `$(this).attr("name")`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if you will check the code on the server again you will see that I updated the script with your proposal but it still doesn't update the count on load. After I console.log(response) i got a Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: There's an error in the code, I'm testing it. one sec

Comment: @Alin Check the solution. Error fixed and it works fine on my machine

Comment: Have a great evening, you sure made mine a lot better :)

Comment: PS: I am sorry but I cannot award the bounty to you for the next 23 hours...After that I promise I will.

Comment: Also, I would like to ask, is there a better way of getting the sum of all than setting an interval like this : `setInterval(function() {
 var sum = 0;
 $('.sum').each(function()
 {
  sum += parseInt($(this).html());
 });
 $('.total').html('Total: '+sum);
}, 10);`

Comment: @Alin You could give a name to that function, move it outside of the interval, and call it in the `success` right after `$('.small'+name).html(response);`. Because, from the current code, the values will only change on click or on load. There's no real need to calculate the sum 100 times every second. Just do it when there's an update (when the AJAX call succeeds)

Comment: Sorry, I think I was brain damaged last night...I made it work by naming it `function calculateSum() {...})` and calling it `calculateSum();` inside the success...

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the AJAX request after the page completely loads using `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "downloadsCount.php", 
        data: { buttonName:name }, 
        async: false,
        method: "POST", 
        success: function(response) { 
            $('.small' + name).html(response);
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: The whole thing already is wrapped in $(document).ready(function(){..}); I just didn't find it relevant to write so...

Comment: @Alin Try adding the `async: false,` attribute to your AJAX request. I also updated the answer with this.

Comment: I have, unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem...you can see it here :http://imagins.ro/count/